# Why do you use Cursor in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have been working on SQL Server for a long time and recently I was moved to a project which uses Oracle.

While I have heard of the term `Cursor`, I have not encountered one in the SQL Server. So my questions are:

1. Why do you even bother declaring `Cursor` in SQL Server? (or under what circumstances do you actually need a `cursor`?)
2. Why declaring `cursor` is mandatory in Oracle?

Comment: For SQL Server, you **can** use a cursor, but you want to avoid it if at all possible. Your performance is going to be consistently better if you can find a set-based approach. It's an easy trap for someone with programming experience, but little to no SQL experience.

Comment: In SQL Server, I think of a cursor as a procedural element.  IMO, SQL Server handles set-based commands much more efficiently than procedural commands.  That's why you'll see so many comments about avoiding cursors.  I haven't worked with Oracle much since ver 9.  IMO opinion, Oracle's PL/SQL is better suited to handle procedural code than SQL Server's tsql, but this can be highly debatable.  Perhaps other Oracle experts can add their input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why do you even bother declaring Cursor in SQL Server? (or under what circumstances do you actually need a cursor?)** Anytime you can't do set based processing record by record processing may be needed; then you would need to use a cursor.  Set based logic is all or nothing when in the transaction.  Perhaps I'm processing individual records and I'm willing to accept situations where partial works.  In this case I could manage each record individually get 99% complete and have the one that "fails" write out to a log.  However *usually* this too can be done via set based logic if one thinks it though.

**Why declaring cursor is mandatory in Oracle?**
Unlike SQL server which returns data sets directly, Oracle returns data sets via REF CURSOR from package, procedure and function.  So if you want a dataset back to work with, you must user a REF cursor.

Answer (score 1):

`Cursor` returns the consistent data on the time of the cursor opening. 
To show this I will open a cursor then I will change a row and I will compare the results of the database and the cursor:

```
SQL> conn hr/hr
Connected.
SQL> select employee_id, email from employees;

EMPLOYEE_ID EMAIL                                                               
----------- -------------------------                                           
        100 SKING                                                               
        101 NKOCHHAR                                                            
...
        205 SHIGGINS                                                            
        206 WGIETZ                                                              

107 rows selected.

SQL> var rc refcursor

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  begin
  2    open :rc for 
  3      select employee_id
  4           , email 
  5        from employees 
  6       order by 1;
  7* end;
SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> update employees set email = 'xxxxxx' where employee_id = 206;

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> print rc

EMPLOYEE_ID EMAIL                                                               
----------- -------------------------                                           
        100 SKING                                                               
        101 NKOCHHAR                                                            
...
        205 SHIGGINS                                                            
        206 WGIETZ                                                              

107 rows selected.

SQL> select employee_id, email from employees;

EMPLOYEE_ID EMAIL                                                               
----------- -------------------------                                           
        100 SKING                                                               
        101 NKOCHHAR                                                            
...
        205 SHIGGINS                                                            
        206 xxxxxx                                                              

107 rows selected.
```

As you can see cursor has the data that was in the database in the time of cursor opening. This is very important behavior, assume you want to work with bank accounts, for example, you want to calculate the sum. If someone changes the table data you will have consistent data and you will give the right answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple situations when you need to use cursor in sql server and they are probably the same as in oracle. For example if you need to call a stored proc for every row of a dataset you need to use a cursor since you cannot do that with a "regular" query.